# Checking if files already exist and are over a certain size in Google Drive folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to iterate through a list of class codes and check if a file already exists with that name in a specific Google drive folder.

I have it working but it is very slow and I think I must be missing a trick. There are 107 unique class codes and my code does each, one at a time. I didnt know if there was a way to get the names of all files in a folder and check against that?

Here is my code:

```
function ClassDataPacksProgress() {
  var dateStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var foldersave=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderkeygoeshere);
  var fetch='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+mainSSKey+'/export?format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=false'
  var classCodeSheet=ss.getSheetByName('ClassCodes')
  var maxRowNum=classCodeSheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var dataRange=classCodeSheet.getRange(1, 1, maxRowNum, 1);
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  var count = 0
  for (var r=0;r<data.length-1;r++){      
      var classCode = data[r][0]
      var name=classCode + " " + dateStamp + ".pdf";
      var filechk = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
      var chk=filechk.hasNext();
      if (chk === false) {
       }
      else {
        var file = filechk.next()
        if (file.getSize() > 3000){
          count = count + 1
          }
       }

   }
}
```

Any help would be amazing!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Search for all files with the date stamp and "pdf" in the title:

```
function ClassDataPacksProgress() {
  //Your code at top

  var allFiles,file;

  allFiles = foldersave
    .searchFiles('title contains "' + dateStamp + '" and title contains ".pdf"');

   while (allFiles.hasNext()) {
     file = files.next();
     Logger.log(file.getName());

     if (file.getSize() > 3000){
       count = count + 1
     }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to search by file size.  Your present code is not searching by folder, but searching the entire Drive.